# QualityCenter Excel-AddIn

Tags: excel, vba, hp-quality-center

When using QualityCenter's excel add-in to upload testcases or requirements, I get an Excel error "compiler error in hidden module: tsFieldMappings" when excel launches the dialog to setup the mapping between excel-columns and QC-fields.

This error and many solutions can be found using google. None of them apply to me :-(

I have asked local support and our remote QC-support (in india), no clues besides reinstalling QC-AddIn and/or Excel or resetting my whole user profile ...

A collegue logged in to my laptop and can use it easily.

=> So my personal configuration is broken somehow.

**Questions:**

1. What is this Error about exactly ?
2. Can I get an excel error log to analyse it myself?
3. Anyone knows the (root) cause of this error for this addin?

BTW: I am not admin on my machine.

Software Versions:

- Excel 2010 (Office Standard) 14.0.7015.1000 (32 Bit)
- Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1.
- QC Export to ALM Addin has 11.0.0.61

Comment: You probably need to explain which of the "many solutions" you found on Google that didn't work.  For example, you need access to the XLSTART folders.  This could be the reason your colleague works and you don't.

Comment: That was fast ... I checked for C:/ Program files / Microsoft office / Office 14/ XLSTART and could add a file to the TDAddin/Tasks folder.